# How to convert a git merger into a rebase

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I have merged two branches. Now it seems that I had to rebase the two branches. What should I do? Here is what I am looking for

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on the **develop** branch:

Revert the merge:

> git reset --hard [last-commit-before-merge]

Go to experiment branch:

> git checkout experiment

Perform the rebase:

> git rebase -i develop

Comment: what does git reset --hard do?

Comment: It changes pointer of the current branch to a specified commit. You can consider it as removing part of commits in your current branch. This operation is reversible if you will data from "git reflog"

Answer (score 2):

You can just reset your branch to the point before the merge and then perform a rebase instead. So if this is your situation:

```
                       experiment
                          ↓
  A --- B --- C --- D --- E
 /                         \
* --- * --- * ----- X ----- M
                            ↑
                          master
```

Then reset `master` to commit `X`, and then perform the rebase on experiment:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard X
git checkout experiment
git rebase master
```

Then you will end up with this:

```
* -- * -- * -- X -- A' -- B' -- C' -- D' -- E'
               ↑                            ↑
             master                     experiment
```

So the merge commit `M` is gone and your experiment branch is rebased onto `master`. You can then fast-forward master and get rid of the experiement branch.

Comment: Then reset master to commit X. (not B)

Comment: @PankajSinghal Right, thanks! I changed the labels right at the end and forgot to adjust that :)